# Why the index in dynamodb be called 'secondary index' ? Why add 'secondary'?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb-index

OK! I just want to know why secondary index. Who is the first?
I am from China. Maybe the problem of translation.I am just a little curious.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey

Comment: Actually,I have already read this doc. But I still do not understand. And now, i think i know what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i saw another doc.I think i find the answser.

In this doc.I find this --

[Improving Data Access with Secondary Indexes](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html)

"Amazon DynamoDB provides fast access to items in a table by specifying primary key values. However, many applications might benefit from having one or more secondary (or alternate) keys available, to allow efficient access to data with attributes other than the primary key. To address this, you can create one or more secondary indexes on a table, and issue Query or Scan requests against these indexes."

In this sentence, we can see this keyword -- "secondary (or alternate) keys".In English,'primary' can mean main , or more important.But when we translate into Chinese,we lost their relationship. 
So,"Who is the first ?". I think primary key is the 'first' that i care about.

All the above answers are from official doc and self-understanding.If you have any questions, please correct me.